# C# Streamreader: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, web-crawler

As this is very common problem but there is no proper solution which can fix my issue.

I am experiencing this issue when try to read / load data from StreamReader

Here is my code.

```
public bool WebSiteIsAvailable(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response)
{
    request.Timeout = 15000;
    request.Method = "HEAD"; // As per Lasse's comment

    try
    {
        using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public string ParseHtml(string html)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(html);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));

    if (WebSiteIsAvailable(request, response))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();

        sr.Close();
        response.Close(); // While using WebResponse please make sure that you close the response stream ie(.close) else it would hang the machine after certain repeated execution.Eg
    }
    else
    {
        response.Close();
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: are you maintaining code or writing new code? If new code, please consider using `System.Net.Http` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0).

You are also calling `GetResponse` two times in a row, is that the wanted behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider removing the WebSiteIsAvailable() function and merging that logic into your ParseHtml function. You're calling the GetResponse() twice, and that may be the source of your problem.

Also, the flow seems a bit odd. You call GetResponse() and instantiate a stream reader and THEN you call WebSiteIsAvailable. If WebSiteIsAvailable is going to return false, you've already got a problem before you ever make that call.